# Not declaring a property as optional results in "property not initialized at super.init()" error

Tags: properties, compiler-errors, swift, optional-variables

I have written the following code for a protocol. I pass the the reference to the delegate variable and use it to call interface/protocol functions. However, if I put `?` for declaring the Protocol object, no error is generated. If I don't, it gives me an error

> property self.delegate is not intialized at super.init().

Why is that?

```
protocol DownloadDataInterface
{
    func downloadCompleted(data : NSDictionary);
}

class DownloadData: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    var data : NSMutableData!;

    var delegate : DownloadDataInterface;


    init(keywords: String!)
    {
        super.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by the end of the `init` every property must have been initialized. Either at the declaration site or within the code of the `init`.

Properties that are optional or implicitly unwrapped optional are the only exception (because, after all, that's what being optional means).